# Website Uptime Online/Offline PHP Script

Tags: php

This is what I currently have. It doesn't work, what needs to be done to fix it?

```
<?php
$status =  GetServerStatus('http://domain.com',80)
?>

<?php
function GetServerStatus($site, $port)
{
    $status = array("OFFLINE", "ONLINE");
    $fp = @fsockopen($site, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);

    if (!$fp) {
        return $status[0];
    } else { 
        return $status[1];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Does your server support sockets? Are you runnong this on a free web host?

Comment: What does "It doesn't work" mean? Please provide more detailed information and errors.

Comment: For a start, remove the @ from in front of fsockopen to see if there are errors or warnings being suppressed.  Also remove the 2 parameter so that you can see if it is taking longer to connect to the server.  This is possible especially if the server is busy and/or you have DNS issues and you're using a hostname.

Comment: Using the @ stop error output. Getting rid of that would help. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't put in the http:// part.

```
echo GetServerStatus('www.domain.com', 80);

function GetServerStatus($site, $port)
{
    $fp = @ fsockopen($site, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
    return ($fp)
        ? 'ONLINE'
        : 'OFFLINE';
}
```

- https://www.php.net/fsockopen

Fist parameter should be a hostname not a URL.